# Driver code in one language and executors in different languages

Tags: apache-spark

How can I use different programming languages to define the logic of my executors, than what I use for the driver? Is this possible at all?

E.g.: I would write the driver in Scala, then call different functions written in Java, Python for the distributed processing of the dataset.

Comment: No you can't . Driver is the one which serializes your function to be executed in executor.

Comment: O.K. Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

You could, but only under certain circumstances, and with some work.
It should be possible to use the code generation feature of SparkSQL/DataSet to implement methods in other languages and call them through JNI or other interfaces.

Furthermore, the generated code is Java code, so technically you are already running Java code, independently of which language you use to program the Spark program.

As far as I know, it's also possible to use Python UDFs inside a Spark program written in Java or Scala.

With the RDD API it should also be possible to call libraries in other programming languages - with Scala-Java mixes being trivial to implement, and non-JVM languages needing the appropriate bridging logic.

There's - at least in current versions of Spark - a performance penalty to pay, for getting data out of the JVM and back into it, so I would use this sparingly, and only when you have weighed the performance pros and cons carefully.